# Why fullname is not changed when I change textbox content

Tags: angularjs

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>
var app= angular.module('myApp',[]);
app.controller('myController',function($scope){


  $scope.firstName = 'John';
  $scope.lastName = 'Smith';
  $scope.fullName = $scope.firstName + ' ' + $scope.lastName;
});
</script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">



  FirstName <input type="text" ng-model="firstName">
  LastName <input type="text" ng-model="lastName">
 <p>Full name is {{fullName}}</p>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

The result is:

Full name is John Smith

Now, on chrome browser, I go and type Carl in FirstName textbox, I expected the result is changed to

Full name is Carl Smith.

However, it does not change.

Where am I wrong?

Comment: The value of `$scope.fullName` is still "John Smith" because you are not changing it

Comment: $scope.firstName is not changed to Carl when I change the content of FirstName Textbox??

Comment: Yes `firstName` is changed, but not `fullName`

Comment: thanks. But i thought $scope.fullName is changed because of $scope.fullName = $scope.firstName + ' ' + $scope.lastName; I can't understand why $scope.fullName is called only once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `$scope.fullname` is evaluated once, when the controller is created. You can use `$watch` on the specific variables or instead use a function to construct the full name like

```
$scope.getFullname = function() { return $scope.firstName + ' ' + $scope.lastName; };
```

And then call it with `<p>Full name is {{ getFullname() }}</p>`.

The easiest way would be two use the variables directly in the template, e.g.

```
<p>Full name is {{ firstName }} {{ lastName }}.</p>
```

Comment: why $scope.fullname does not automatically update when I change $scope.firstName by changing the content of FirstName Text Box?

Comment: Because when the controller is created, `fullname` is constructed with the two values. But it is evaluated to the static string of both values. It does not automatically detect the change of one variable. This can be achieved by `$watch`ing both variables and change `fullname`, whenever one of them changes.